# Proof for dense and closed

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the only closed and dense subset in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ itself. This is because for a closed set, you cannot get arbitrarily close to any point outside the set. So, this is why the only closed and dense subset of a set, is the set itself.

However, I'm having trouble proving this formally.

Comment: Dense = "the closure is $\Bbb R$". Closed = "the closure is the set itself". Can you conclude?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "the closure."

Comment: But, is that the key to proving my above statement more formally?

Comment: @TobinBrooks it is certainly one way to do it.  For a set $A$, do you know what its "closure" refers to?  Usually, it's written as $cl(A)$ or $\overline{A}$

Comment: No, I've never seen it like that. But just looking it up on wikipedia, it seems to be the set that contains all the points of the set, along with its limit points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem with your argument is that you're considering points outside of $\Bbb R$ when there is no reason to do so.

Suppose that $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ is dense and closed.  Then, every point $r \in \Bbb R$ is a limit point of $A$ (that is, every open neighborhood of $r$ contains an element of $A$).  However, by the definition of a closed set (or by the appropriate theorem): if a point $r$ is a limit point of $A$, then that point must also be an element of $A$.  Since every $r$ is a limit point of $A$, every $r$ is an element of $A$.

So, $A = \Bbb R$.

Comment: Wow thanks! that makes a lot of sense, and uses concepts I'm already familiar with

Comment: Glad to help.${}$